# Destruct object by type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, inheritance, types

Say I have the following two interfaces

```
interface Parent {
  prop1: string
  prop2: string
}

interface Child extends Parent {
  prop3: string
  prop4: string
  ....
  prop100: string
}
```

Is it possible, given an instance of `Child`, to get all properties of `Parent`?

```
function useChild(child: Child) {
  const parentProps: Parent = magicFunctionToGetAllParentProperties(child);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(parentProps));
}

useChild({prop1: "foo", prop2: "bar", prop50: "baz"}) // Prints {prop1: "foo", prop2: "bar"}
```

Failed attempt:

```
  const {...parent,...other}: {parent: Parent, other: Child}= child;
```

Comment: No, types don't exist at runtime.

Comment: This is a very strange requirement and it seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Types don't exist at runtime, but the compiler could generate the list of keys that exist in `Parent`, and use them to copy over all the contents to `parentProps`.

Comment: @FudgeFudge But it can't / doesn't

Comment: Well you can always do it manually `const {prop1, prop2} = child; JSON.stringify({prop1, prop2})` but otherwise no, there is no way to do it